# c++ fmod returns NaN for fmod(0.0,1.0)

Tags: c++

I'm encountering a very odd situation:
In a multi-threaded app I'm developing, at a certain code point `fmod(x,y)` returns `-1.#IND00` while `double x = 0.0` and `double y = 1.0`. Of course I double-checked the values of `x` and `y`. What is even more weird is that if I add a dummy test codeline `f=fmod(0.0,1.0);` before the `f=fmod(x,y);` line then `fmod(x,y)` returns `0.0` as expected.

The app is built with multi-threaded Runtime library. (VS2005) What could be the reason?

Edit 1:
After hours of further researching i've found out that it has something to do with the FPU status register. When the zero divide exception flag is set then it returns -1.#IND00 else the correct 0.0 value is returned. I still have no clue what's going on here. My code is not messing with that FPU status register, but it is about a plug-in so i have no control over what the plugin host is doing. But even when the zero divide exception flag is set, why does this make a difference here as the fmod denom value = 1.0. Is this a bug in the fmod implementation? Anyone heard of such bug? This is driving me nuts.

Edit 2:
I'm quite sure this is a bug in the 64 bit fmod implementation in the CRT lib in VS2005. When the FPU status register DivByZero flag is already raised upon calling fmod this gives a wrong result. I'd love to 100% prove this by some test code but i can't do inline assembly for x64 with VS2005 in order to force a divide by zero with the FPU, which would set that flag, then i'd call fmod.

Comment: When a math function returns random nonsensical results, you've got much larger problems than can be diagnosed from five lines of vague description.

Comment: How do you mean? I have no clue at all how this could be possible, so i also don't know what info is relevant and what not. I tried to add all relevant info. What's missing in my description?

Comment: Such behaviour indicates that something is going awfully wrong somewhere -- a race condition, corrupted memory, you name it. But it probably originates from another location in your program, especially with multithreading involved. There's no way to diagnose that with only the point at which the symptom appears, one needs the whole code.

Comment: I had to track down a problem like this once, and it nearly drove me crazy. An HP printer driver was changing a FPU flag, so the program failed only after you printed something to a specific printer.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm that this is a bug in the VS2005 CRT 64 bit implementation of fmod. It's easy to repeat: Make sure the DivByZero flag in the FPU is raised just before calling z=fmod(x,y) where x=0.0 and y=1.0, then z will be NaN which is wrong of course.

So this has nothing to do with multi-threading, nor memory corruption. It's just a bug in that CRT lib.

I made a little test app using VirtualAlloc to have some executable memory in which i put the code bytes to do a divide by zero in the FPU so that the FPU DivByZero flag is raised. (VS2005 can't inline 64 bit assembly code therefore the exe ram trick) Then i do the above mentioned fmod function call and indeed z is displayed as -1.#IND00 = NaN. All steps double-checked in the debugger. QED.

I'm amazed i could not find anything about this CRT bug on the www. Am i the first one to discover this CRT bug?

Anyway, the question has been answered. Conclusion: I'll use an alternative implementation for fmod.

PS: In case someone wants to repeat the test, here are the x86 code bytes i used to force a raised DivByZero flag in the FPU:

```
0xD9,0xEE = fldz
0xD9,0xE8 = fld1
0xD8,0xF1 = fdiv ST(0),ST(1)
0xDD,0xD8 = fstp ST(0) = pop stack
0xDD,0xD8 = fstp ST(0) = pop stack
0xC3 = ret
```

Comment: Congratulations for digging that one out, and sorry for the pessimistic diagnostic ! You can mark your own answer as accepted :)

Comment: Vrish, what optimization were you using ? I'm debugging a similar fmod() problem, it goes away with -g or -O0, but shows up with -O3 and --fast-math

Comment: @Vrish, also did you use trunc() in your alternative implementation ? I'm concerned it may be affected by the same FPU flag issue

Answer (score 1):

If you use constant parameters, the value is likely to be hard-coded by your compiler. So this code doesn't actually invoke fmod:

```
f=fmod(0.0,1.0);
```

Instead a constant floating point value is assigned. This explains why your dummy line calculates the correct result.
Seems to be a problem with the standard/math library.

Comment: Yes i also suspect a (threading) prob/bug in the C runtime library. I've searched the web for references on that but didn't find anything, that's why i posted the question here.

Comment: I understand that when using constants, it's hard-coded. But why does that influence the result of the fmod function call?

Comment: Try to reproduce it in a minimal / hello world environment. If you're not successful try to isolate the error by commenting out parts of your code base step by step until you get rid of the effect.